# Computer-generated Variables VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, variables, visual-studio-2012, global, universal

This probably will seem like a simple process, but I'm new to programming, so I don't know how to do it.

I'm programming in VB.Net and I want the computer to generate a new set of global variables every time the user presses Button X. Naturally we don't know how many times the button will be pressed, which is why I need the computer to create the variables. Also, how do I tell the computer to assign a new number to each variable? For example:

ButtonX clicked first time:
NewVariable1 created

ButtonX clicked a second time:
NewVariable2 created.

I hope this makes sense. I can provide more details if necessary. I need the variables generated to be accessible from many different classes, and maybe even from one load to the next, if possible.

Comment: Really vague question.  What exactly are you going to do with these new "variables"?  Quick answer is to use a Dictionary() with the "variable" name as a **Key**.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll look into using a Dictionary().

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [List(Of T)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class. Create a list that is globally accessible and add another value each time the button is pressed.

```
globaList.Add(newValue)
```

This assumes that all the variables are of the same type.
Later on, you can access the list items (=variables) by their index. This retrieves the value that was added last:

```
Dim value = globalList(globalList.Count - 1)
```

You can also change values in the list:

```
globalList(index) = newValue
```

Comment: Thank you. I will have a look at that.